# rewrite url after remove extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need your help.

I have a problem to rewrite a dynamic url after extension removed, I've rewritten this url but not works:

.htaccess like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#add www  1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mondomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mondoamin.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#remove .php extension  2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$  /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs  3
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#rewrite url 4
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /article\.php\?id_ article =([^&\ ]+)([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^/article/%1?%2 [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.#?\ ]+\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/     
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php $1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

results: 
1+2+3  works fine but 4 not works

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try reordering the rules and keep 301 rules before internal rewrites:

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#add www  1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mondomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mondoamin.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#rewrite url 4
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /article\.php\?id_article=([^&\ ]+)([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /article/%1?%2 [L,R=301] 

RewriteRule ^article/([^/]+)/?$ /article.php?id_article=$1 [L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.#?\ ]+\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/     
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php $1 [R=301,L]

#remove .php extension  2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$  /$1 [R=301,L]

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs  3
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess and for which URL it is not working?

Comment: .htaccess is located in the root directory of my site.                   here is the url that does not work:                         RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /article\.php\?id_ article =([^&\ ]+)([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^/article/%1?%2 [L,R=301]

Comment: You didn't tell for which URL (in your browser) it didn't work.

Comment: no! ;(                                                 i have a same error: Internal Server Error
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.       i'm not sure if the problem comes from the url in web page(source code),i have not changed url in the source code of my web page!                                                           Sorry for my bad english and I hope you can understand me.

Comment: Is there any other htaccess in your system anywhere? Can you post your latest htaccess code in your question?

Answer (score 0):

this is the my last .htaccess code:

Options -Multiviews

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

## add www

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mondomain.fr$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mondomaine.fr/$1 [R=301,L]

## rewrite dynamic url

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /article.php\?id_article=([^&\ ]+)([^\ ]*)

RewriteRule ^ /article/%1?%2 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^ article/([^/]+)/?$ /article.php?id_article=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.#?\ ]+.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/

RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+).php $1 [R=301,L]

## remove .php extension

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$  /$1 [R=301,L]

## Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index.php [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]

RewriteRule (.*?)index.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

## Directs all EE web requests through the site index file

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: any idea please,  Excuse  me  anubhava i have added .htaccess as a response due to the length of the file.